# How to send multiple comments to content.js from popup.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message, message-passing

### Actual behavior:

When I click any single button like btn1/btn2/btn3, the console shows "message",
"message 2" and "message 3".

### Expected behavior:

- When I click button 1, the console should show the text "message".
- When I click button 2, the console should show the text "message 2".
- When I click button 3, the console should show the text "message 3".

Popup.js

```
 document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
      let message= document.getElementById('one-input').value
           chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
           chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, message );
         })
       

 document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click', function(){
      let message2= document.getElementById('two-input').value;
           chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) { 
           chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, message2);
         });

        document.querySelector('#btn3').addEventListener('click', function(){
      let message3= document.getElementById('three-input').value;
         chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {              
         chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, message3);
         });
```

Content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
       console.log("message")

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message2,sender, sendResponse ) {
      console.log("message2")

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message3, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log("message3")
```

Comment: paste error details and html code

Comment: Simply send an object like `{type: 1, data: elem.value}` and use message.type + message.data in just one onMessage listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm is ther another way?  As a beginner i don't quite get that.

Comment: No, it's the only correct method. Simply replace message2 in sendMessage with `{type: 2, data: document.getElementById('two-input').value}`. In your single onMessage listener you'll check message.type and then use message.data accordingly.